# Solving a transformation equation involving vectors and quaternions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation, quaternions

I'd like to solve the following equation for $c$, where $a$, $c$, and $d$ are position vectors represented by quaternions with $w$ (the real component) set to $0$ and $b$ is a unit quaternion:
$$a+(b*c*b^{-1})=d$$

The $(b*c*b^{-1})$ part of the equation is used to rotate $c$ by $b$, as described here: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/transforms/

In other words:
$$originalPosition+transformPosition=newPosition$$

Basic algebra leads me to believe that the following is correct, but I'm not getting the correct answer, probably because quaternion multiplication isn't commutative:
$$c=\frac{d-a}{b*b^{-1}}$$

Plus, $b*b^{-1}$ is a quaternion with $x$, $y$, and $z$ equal to $0$ and $w$ equal to $1$, effectively dividing by $1$. So I'm basically computing:
$$c=d-a$$

What is the correct equation for $c$?

Comment: Because quaternions are not commutative, you cannot divide.  You have to pre or post multiply to manipulate both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a+(b*c*b^{-1})=d$$
$$b*c*b^{-1}=d-a$$
$$b^{-1}b*c*b^{-1}=b^{-1}(d-a)$$
$$c*b^{-1}=b^{-1}(d-a)$$
$$c*b^{-1}b=b^{-1}(d-a)b$$
$$c=b^{-1}(d-a)b$$

Comment: Thank you for the insight! To divide, I was previously multiplying by the inverse, but I didn't do it properly. Once again, I really appreciate the detailed answer.